# Is this concept applicable for a graph database?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I have been reading about Graph databases and want to know if this type of structure is applicable to it:

Company > Has user Accounts > Accounts send out facebook posts (which are available to all users)

Up to here - I think this makes sense - yes it would be a good use of Graph. A post has a relationship to any accounts and you can find out the direction both ways - posts for a company and which posts were sent by which users or companies.

However

- Users get added and deleted on a daily basis and I need a record store of how many there were at a given time
- Accounts are getting results for each post (likes/friends) which I need to store on a daily basis
- I need to find out how many likes a company received (on any given day)
- I also need to find out how many likes a user received
- I need to find out how many likes a user received per post
- You would need to store Likes as a group and then date-value - can you even have "sub" properties?

I struggle at this point unless you are storing lots of date-value property lists per node. Is that the way you would do it? If I wanted to find out the later 2 points for example would it be as efficient as a RDBMS?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple example of a Graph data model that seems to cover your stated use cases. (Since nodes can have multiple labels, all `Company` and `User` nodes are also `Entity` nodes -- to simplify the model.)

```
(:Company:Entity {id:100})-[:HAS_USER]->(:User:Entity {id: 200})
(:Entity)-[:SENT]->(:Post {date: 123, msg: "I like cats!"})
(:Entity)-[:LIKES {date: 234}]->(:Post)
```

Your use cases:

1. *Users get added and deleted on a daily basis and I need a record store of how many there were at a given time.*

   How to count all users:

   ```
   MATCH (u:User)
   RETURN COUNT(*);
   ```

   How to count a company's users:

   ```
   MATCH (c:Company {id:100})-[:HAS_USER]->(u:User)
   RETURN COUNT(*);
   ```
2. *I need to find out how many likes a company received (on any given day)*

   ```
   MATCH (c:Company {id: 100})-[:SENT]->(p:Post)<-[:LIKES {date:234}]-()
   RETURN COUNT(*)
   ```
3. *I also need to find out how many likes a user received*

   ```
   MATCH (u:User {id:200})-[:SENT]->(p:Post)<-[:LIKES]-()
   RETURN COUNT(*);
   ```
4. *I need to find out how many likes a user received per post*

   ```
   MATCH (u:User {id:200})-[:SENT]->(p:Post)<-[:LIKES]-()
   RETURN p, COUNT(*)
   ```
5. *You would need to store Likes as a group and then date-value - can you even have "sub" properties?*

   You do not need to explicitly group likes by date (if that is what you mean). Such "groupings" can be easily obtained by the appropriate query (e.g., in #2 above).

Comment: So if your opinion then a Graph database would match our requirements. I'm slightly confused though about how you would do the storing of dates per item which I would traditionally store in a simple table and link back to say the post. So for example:
10/2/15 - 1 like - Post 1, 11/2/15 - 2 likes - Post 1 etc. If that data is not grouped where and how would you store it? Is it on the node such as date-10/2/15:1? Thanks

Comment: @Antony try to wrap your head around [Multi-Model Database | OrientDB Manual](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Tutorial-Document-and-graph-model.html) and [TinkerPop3 > Issues > meta-properties and multi-properties for security and history #489](https://github.com/tinkerpop/tinkerpop3/issues/489). That is where I'd try to search the answer while you aren't in the vendor lock yet

Comment: Thanks - I like the OrientDB. So am I right in thinking I would use the Graph for core data and then Clusters for storing history related to that element?